# Contenteditable, focus, and browser inconsistencies in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, contenteditable

I'm trying to account for the differences between Chrome (v. 42.0.2311.152) and Firefox (v. 38.0.1) visible in this snippet:

```js
$('#test').focus()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test' contenteditable='true'>
  <p>First paragraph</p>
  <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**In Chrome:**

- the div gets focused with a cursor before the first paragraph
- tapping the backspace key at that point does not delete the paragraph tag

**In Firefox:**

- the div is not focused
- manually placing the cursor before the first paragraph and tapping backspace deletes the paragraph tag

The behavior of Chrome is what I would "expect" - how can I make Firefox behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's focus method doesn't work very well with contenteditable. You should use the browser's focus method instead:

```
$('#test').get(0).focus()
```